# can't edit QML files in designer mode

Tags: qt, qml, qt-designer, qtquick-designer

i am trying out qml designer using **`qtcreator 2.0.1`** but the designer tab is disabled when i create a new qml project.

Can qml be edited in designer mode like `ui` files in c++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Qt Creator 2.0.1, the QML Designer is **disabled by default**. You'll need to enable it manually by going into Help -> About Plugins..., checking QmlDesigner, and then restarting Qt Creator. However, it is disabled **for good reason**.

You should really upgrade to at least Qt Creator 2.1.0, or to the just released 2.2 beta.

I'd suggest going for the beta, since its QML Design mode has seen a bit of a rewrite since the 2.1 version, and you would have a chance of providing feedback about any bugs before the final version is out.

Comment: In Qt Creator 2.0.1, the QML Designer was still in many ways unfinished, and very buggy (it would often crash Qt Creator).